# How to handle Twitter OAuth in a popup window and close the popup and reload the parent window in react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth-2.0, oauth, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to do oauth in a react app using passport js and want to open the twitter oauth process in a popup window after a button click, authenticate the user, close the popup and then reload the parent window.
Currently after the authentication it falls back to the callback url in the popup window.
I know this question have been asked before, but i've spent the past few days and found no right answers.
Does anybody know how can this be achieved?

I tried closing the popup window after authentication by sending res.send("window.close(); "); from the server and it works but have no clue about reloading the parent window.

Comment: So your specific question is: How do I refresh my browser tab _from_ a popup? Does `window.opener.location.reload();` work?

Comment: I didn't simplify the question to that because I thought there might be other ways people handle this, but yeah that's a way to achieve this. And no, I tried that line, It didn't work.